# Error de conversión

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mvc

tengo este dato en SQLServer:

**Titulo** que está en **float**

Estoy realizando una consulta en c# mvc para cargar este dato pero la verdad es que me está dando Error de conversión, ¿Alguien sabe como se convierte correctamente?

**Clase:**

```
public class ProvidusCuotas{
        private float titulo { get; set; }
        private string nombre { get; set; }
        private string cuota { get; set; }
        public ProvidusCuotas(float titulo, string nombre, string cuota) {
            this.titulo = titulo;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.cuota = cuota;
        }
        public ProvidusCuotas() {}
    }
```

**Modelo:**

```
public List<ProvidusCuotas> cargarDatos(){
            List<ProvidusCuotas> salida = new List<ProvidusCuotas>();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("cadenadeConexion");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("SELECT titulo, apellido +', '+nombre,max(Cuota) FROM V_CuetaWeb GROUP BY titulo, apellido, nombre ORDER BY titulo ASC", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read()){
                float titulo = Convert.ToSingle(dr.GetFloat(0));//aquí es donde sale el error de conversión
                string nombre = dr.GetString(1);
                string cuota = Convert.ToString(dr.GetDouble(2));
                ProvidusCuotas p = new ProvidusCuotas(titulo,nombre, cuota);
                salida.Add(p);
            }
            conn.Close();
            return salida;
        }
```

Error: `System.InvalidCastException: 'La conversión especificada no es válida.'`

Adjunto imagen de la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por que haces `Convert.ToSingle` de un float para almacenarlo en un float?

Comment: porque aún cuando no hago la conversión, el error persiste e intenté varias conversiones "tontas" para ver si se podía solucionar

Comment: Aha,entiendo. Entonces el problema debe ser que tu consulta trae en la primera columna algun valor que no es posible convertir a float, por lo que la excepción la está enviando `dr.GetFloat(0)`.O sea, básicamente  `titulo` en `V_CuetaWeb` en alguna fila (o en todas) tiene valores que no se pueden convertir a float de manera automatica.

Comment: La observacion de @Pikoh es correcta. Muestranos los valores que intentas convertir.

Comment: Adjunté la imagen de la vista en la cual muestro que titulo es un float. Básicamente, quiero mostrar el valor en mvc pero lo convierta o no, sale el mismo error

Comment: Mustra que datos trae titulo puede ser que en uno haya algo no valido, por que veo que acepta NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aconsejo cambiar el codigo para usar los nombre de los campos en lugar de los indices

```
public List<ProvidusCuotas> cargarDatos()
{
    List<ProvidusCuotas> salida = new List<ProvidusCuotas>();

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("cadenadeConexion"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string query = @"SELECT titulo, apellido +', '+nombre as fullname, max(Cuota) as cuotas
                        FROM V_CuetaWeb 
                            GROUP BY titulo, apellido, nombre 
                        ORDER BY titulo ASC";
        SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read()){
            float titulo = Convert.ToSingle(dr["titulo"]);
            string nombre = dr["fullname"].ToString();
            string cuota = dr["cuotas"].ToString();

            ProvidusCuotas p = new ProvidusCuotas(titulo,nombre, cuota);
            salida.Add(p);
        }
    }

    return salida;
}
```

al usar los nombres evitas problemas que puedieran estar relacionados a una incorrecta referencia

Algo que si noto deberias evaluar es porque un campo `titulo` es numerico, mientras que uno que representa `cuotas` es un string, creo que deberias ser al contrario, las cuotas son numericas

igual siempre se puede usar el `tryparse()`

```
float titulo = 0;
if(single.TryParse(dr["titulo"].ToString(), out titulo)){
   //si ingresa aqui es que no puedo convertir
};
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió tu respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Veo 3 cosas en tu problemática:

1. La conversión adecuada para un tipo de dato float de SQL a C# es "Double", mira esta documentación: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings
2. Cuando pasas  los datos del DataReader para el titulo, estás convirtiendo a "Single", deberías hacer "Convert.ToDouble(xxx)".
3. Deberías validar si el dato es = a DbNull.